# jquery php issue

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

Hey everyone. This one is puzzling me. I'm using PHP and Jquery. I am making an ajax request to a PHP file containing a get url. Eg. `Path/to/file/?ID=369`

The request goes out fine, I've watched it in fire bug.

However in the PHP file, the `ID` variable doesn't exist. When I do

```
var_dump($_GET)
```

I can see that there are two arrays inside the GET array. These are JSON and action.

Can anyone explain to me what's going on here and how I can receive my `ID` variable?

here are my codes:

```
<?php 

  $program_price_id = $_GET['id']; 
  $programDepatures = getProgramDepaturesGreaterThanToday($program_price_id); 
  echo "[{optionValue: 0, optionDisplay: 'Select a date'}"; 
  while ($programDepartureData = mysql_fetch_array($programDepatures)) { 
      echo ", {optionValue: ". 
              $programDepartureData['id'].", optionDisplay: '".
              tidyDateEnglish($programDepartureData['departure_date'])."'}"; 
    } 

  echo "]"; 

 ?>
```

Best wishes,

Mike

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: Can you attach/paste your code somewhere?

Comment: Use 'params:{}' object for passing params to request

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to specify the ajax method you are using.It might be a $.ajax, $.get or $.getJson.

but i use $.ajax and here is a snippet

```
$.ajax({
                            url:"event/service_ajax_handler.php",
                            type: "GET",
                            data: {action:"getTime"},
                            dataType : "json",
                            success: function(data) {
                                $("#cmbTimeRange").html("<option value='-1'>Please select time range</option>");
                                $.each(data, function(){
                                    $("#cmbTimeRange").append("<option value='"+ this.id +"'>" + this.hours +"</option>")
                                });
                            },
                            error: function(){
                                alert("error");
                            }
                        });
```

pay attention to the `data` parameter.  see also 
[getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

Comment: Thanks everyone for your feedback. @void @nick Here is my code `code <?php
  $program_price_id = $_GET['id'];
  $programDepatures = getProgramDepaturesGreaterThanToday($program_price_id);
    echo "[{optionValue: 0, optionDisplay: 'Select a date'}"; 
  while ($programDepartureData = mysql_fetch_array($programDepatures)) {
    echo ", {optionValue: ".$programDepartureData['id'].", optionDisplay: '".tidyDateEnglish($programDepartureData['departure_date'])."'}";
  }
  echo "]";

 
?> `

Answer (score 0):

This may be obvious, but I noticed in the sample URL you have ID capitalized, but in your PHP code you have it lowercase. PHP is case sensitive, so it could be as simple as that.

Comment: That's a typeo on my part I'm afraid, sorry about that. I'm starting to think that the problem is to do with my htaccess. It's incredibly annoying because the variable is there in the request